# Google Map Javascript Api, Angular, Dynamicly Loaded Page

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

What happened past weeks i don't know if google messed things up again. My map stopped working.

I transferred the app Angular for routes. When the contact page loads, **initializeMap** function called. 
I got new browser api key from google console which is not like old. I enabled Javascript Map Api. I entered my URLs in credential.
Sometimes it gives error invalidkey*** but only sometimes.

It works on my domain if i put everything in one single file.
It also works on codepen. I don't know why? There is no error to debug this thing. My beloved javascript.
http://codepen.io/emrahatilkan/pen/bVwzrR

Edit: This is about angular definitely.

Google Map Link in index.html:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY"></script>
```

My URL: **index.html/#/contact** 
I don't know if it is relevant but **contact.html** is inside **pages/** folder.

My Code is in main.js:

```
function initializeMap() {
        console.log('init map'); //this outputs to console
        var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: 39.7944417, lng: 30.4935026 },
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: map.getCenter(),
            map: map,
            title: 'Some Title'
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<h5>Some Title</h5>'

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console of your dev tools?  Are there any network calls to the googlemaps API which are failing?

Comment: Nope. Console is empty. It works on codepen. I added link. Problem is i have to separate some parts because of angular.

Comment: And I don't use this google load event. But function is triggered, it is ok. 'google.maps.event.addDomListener()'

Comment: hmmm, that definitely sounds like your problem.  It's hard to say without seeing the way you've implemented it within your base code, but many times I've seen issues because the map is loaded into a dom element which isn't there yet.  Issues will also occur if the map is loaded into a canvas which is resized or begins hidden and then is shown.

Comment: I understand i have to use a map plugin for angular.

Comment: I am an imbecile. It works now. Css with and height is gone somewhere. Probably accidently removed.

Comment: right on, no worries